# Using regex to wrap images in tags

Tags: php, html, regex

I've been using regex to wrap my images in < a > tags and altering their paths etc.
I know using dom for this is better, having read a lot of threads about wrapping, but I'm unable to understand how to.

This is what I'm using:

```
$comments = (preg_replace('@(<img.+src=[\'"]/uploads/userdirs/admin)(?:.*?/)(.+?)\.(.+?)([\'"].*?>)@i', '<a class="gallery" rel="'.$pagelink.'" href=/uploads/userdirs/'.$who.'/$2.$3>$1/mcith/mcith_$2.$3$4</a>', $comments));
```

It successfully wraps each image in the tags I want. But only if the string provided ($comments) has the right markup.

```
<p><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/1160501362291.png" alt="" width="1280" height="960" /></p>
<p><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/100_Bullets_68_1280x1024.jpg" alt="" width="1280" height="1024" /></p>
```

When presented like this, it works. I'm using tinymce so it wraps in < p > when I do a linebreak with enter. But when I don't do that, when I just insert images one after another so the HTML looks like this, it won't:

```
<p><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/1160501362291.png" alt="" width="1280" height="960" /><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/100_Bullets_68_1280x1024.jpg" alt="" width="1280" height="1024" /></p>
```

It will instead wrap those 2 images in the same < a > tag. Making the output look like this:

```
<p><a class="gallery" rel="test" href="/uploads/userdirs/admin/100_Bullets_68_1280x1024.jpg">
<img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/1160501362291.png" alt="" width="1280" height="960">
<img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/mcith/mcith_100_Bullets_68_1280x1024.jpg" alt="" width="1280" height="1024">
</a></p>
```

Which is wrong. The output I want is this:

```
<p><a class="gallery" rel="test2" href="/uploads/userdirs/admin/100_Bullets_68_1280x1024.jpg"><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/mcith/mcith_100_Bullets_68_1280x1024.jpg" alt="" width="1280" height="1024"></a></p>
<p><a class="gallery" rel="test2" href="/uploads/userdirs/admin/1154686260226.jpg"><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/mcith/mcith_1154686260226.jpg" alt="" width="1280" height="800"></a></p>
```

Comment: If you don't understand how to do it the right way, then you should probably ask how to do it the right way, not get into a conversation on how to get the wrong way working.

Comment: i am doing that though. either way works for me.. if anyone can push me in the right direction toward a dom rewrite, i would be very happy =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've left out a few details, but here's how I would do it using DOMDocument:

```
$s = <<<EOM
<p><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/1160501362291.png" alt="" width="1280" height="960" /></p>
<p><img src="/uploads/userdirs/admin/100_Bullets_68_1280x1024.jpg" alt="" width="1280" height="1024" /></p>
EOM;

$d = new DOMDocument;
$d->loadHTML($s);

foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
    $img_src = $img->attributes->getNamedItem('src')->nodeValue;
    if (0 === strncasecmp($img_src, '/uploads/userdirs/admin', 23)) {
        $a = $d->createElement('a');

        $a->setAttribute('class', 'gallery');
        $a->setAttribute('rel', 'whatever');
        $a->setAttribute('href', '/uploads/userdirs/username/' . $img_src);

        // disconnect image tag from parent
        $img->parentNode->replaceChild($a, $img);

        // and move to anchor
        $a->appendChild($img);
    }
}

echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Comment: thank you so much! that is helping me a whole lot! it works, rewrites no matter what i throw at it. trying to pull the filename out of it so i can do  : 
`$a->setAttribute('href', '/uploads/userdirs/username/thumbnail/' . $img_filename);`
Can domdocument do that?

Comment: I've declared a variable `$img_src` inside the loop that contains the value of the original image location. Is that what you need?

Comment: yup! im using pathinfo now to yoink just the filename =) Thank you so much for helping me understand domdocument.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `.*` in your regular expression with `[^>]*`. The latter means: any character expect than `>`. Because regular expression gets as long match as possible. Without this additional condition, this ends up with two `<img>`'s matched.

Comment: hmm, like this? 

`$comments = (preg_replace('@(<img.+src=[\'"]/uploads/userdirs/admin)(?:[^>]*.?/)(.+?)\.(.+?)([\'"][^>]*.?>)@i', '<a class="gallery" rel="'.$pagelink.'" href=/uploads/userdirs/'.$who.'/$2.$3>$1/mcith/mcith_$2.$3$4</a>', $comments));`
i'm getting the same output using that.

Comment: Adding also some `[^"]` and for `+` specifier helps: `@(<img[^>]+src=['"]/uploads/userdirs/admin)(?:[^"]*?/)([^"]+?).([^"]+?)(['"][^>]*?>)@i`

Comment: But as there was said, using some HTML parser as DOM would be much more safer.