# Wrap segments of HTML with divs (and generate table of contents from HTML-tags) with PHP

Tags: php, regex, dom

My original HTML looks something like this:

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>

<h2>Title of segment one</h2>
<img src="img.jpg" alt="An image of segment one" />
<p>Paragraph one of segment one</p>

<h2>Title of segment two</h2>
<p>Here is a list of blabla of segment two</p>
<ul>
  <li>List item of segment two</li>
  <li>Second list item of segment two</li>
</ul>
```

Now, using PHP (not jQuery), I want to alter it, like so:

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>

<div class="pane">
  <h2>Title of segment one</h2>
  <img src="img.jpg" alt="An image of segment one" />
  <p>Paragraph one of segment one</p>
</div>

<div class="pane">
   <h2>Title of segment two</h2>
   <p>Here is a list of blabla of segment two</p>
   <ul>
     <li>List item of segment two</li>
     <li>Second list item of segment two</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So basically, I wish to wrap all HTML between sets of `<h2></h2>` tags with `<div class="pane" />` The HTML above would already allow me to create an accordion with jQuery, which is fine, but I would like to go a little bit further:

I wish to create an ul of all the `<h2></h2>`sets that were affected, like so:

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#">Title of segment one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Title of segment two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please note that I'm using jQuery tools tabs, to implement the JavaScript part of this system, and it does not require that the hrefs of the .tabs point to their specific h2 counterparts.

My first guess would be to use regular expressions, but I've also seen some people talking about [DOM Document](http://be.php.net/domdocument)

Two solutions exist for this problem in jQuery, but I really need a PHP equivalent:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968303/wrapping-a-series-of-elements-between-two-h2-tags-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912275/automatically-generate-nested-table-of-contents-based-on-heading-tags)
- [Automatically generate nested table of contents based on heading tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912275/automatically-generate-nested-table-of-contents-based-on-heading-tags)

Could anyone please practically assist me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOMDocument can help you with that. I've answered a similar question before:

[using regex to wrap images in tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330763/using-regex-to-wrap-images-in-tags/10331514#10331514)

**Update**

Full code sample included:

```
$d = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

$segments = array(); $pane = null;

foreach ($d->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $h2) {
    // first collect all nodes
    $pane_nodes = array($h2);
    // iterate until another h2 or no more siblings
    for ($next = $h2->nextSibling; $next && $next->nodeName != 'h2'; $next = $next->nextSibling) {
        $pane_nodes[] = $next;
    }

    // create the wrapper node
    $pane = $d->createElement('div');
    $pane->setAttribute('class', 'pane');

    // replace the h2 with the new pane
    $h2->parentNode->replaceChild($pane, $h2);
    // and move all nodes into the newly created pane
    foreach ($pane_nodes as $node) {
        $pane->appendChild($node);
    }
    // keep title of the original h2
    $segments[] = $h2->nodeValue;
}

//  make sure we have segments (pane is the last inserted pane in the dom)
if ($segments && $pane) {
    $ul = $d->createElement('ul');
    foreach ($segments as $title) {
        $li = $d->createElement('li');

        $a = $d->createElement('a', $title);
        $a->setAttribute('href', '#');

        $li->appendChild($a);
        $ul->appendChild($li);
    }

    // add as sibling of last pane added
    $pane->parentNode->appendChild($ul);
}

echo $d->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks, DOMDocument seems to be the way to go. Could you elaborate practically on how to target everything between <h2></h2> and how to deal with the last occurrence of those <h2></h2>?

Comment: @maartenmachiels sure, give me a few hours :)

Comment: @maartenmachiels answer updated, check it out :) of course, I didn't take a few hours to make it =p

Comment: Incredible work, man! I'll be testing the code ASAP and will be back soon to approve your answer...

Comment: you are a GENIUS. Thank you very much! You're code works very well. Some detail questions: for some reason the `href`s of the `ul.tabs` aren't wrapped with `li`s. Also, could you tell me how to prevent the wrapping of the output with `<html>` and `<body>`?

Comment: @maartenmachiels doh! missed that one, updated. The wrapping shouldn't matter to your browser; if it matters to you, you can always add text nodes with a newline in it :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11527/discussion-between-maartenmachiels-and-jack)

Comment: Jack, your solution for wrapping regular spans of flat HTML is insanely valuable for anyone who needs to create section and article wrappers for conversion into HTML5 or for migrating HTML content into structured XML such as DITA or DocBook. This is very hard to do with available methods in PHP's XSLT 1.0-level support. Using your approach, one adds this structure in a DOMDocument pre-pass prior to invoking transformToXML(). Thank you!

Comment: This is great, thanks. But the table-of-contents anchors don't quite work for me. I'm not sure you're laying down anchor titles or linking to them. Would be great to see that.

Comment: @RobertAndrews Oh, it's just an example; the `$a->setAttribute('href', '#')` is where you'd want to make changes; that, and each section would need the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) functions to perform this task.

Answer (score 1):

..a nice PHP html parser is what you need.
[This](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) one is good.
Its a PHP equivalent to jquery.